# AWT button clicks exceed the count value beyond expected

Tags: java, user-interface, awt

I made a quiz app and It displays 10 quiz questions. When user clicks next the count increments and next question is displayed from array. The problem is if i click button faster the count exceeds 10 and when the later click events are handled I get Array index out of bounds exceptions as I am loading only 10 questions from database and storing in array. How do I make sure my count variable is only incremented till 10(i.e. 9 for array index) no matter how many times next is clicked. Also I am trying to display timer of 15 seconds and i call repaint every second to update it but I have also added an image and it repaints image ass well every second. I want to avoid repainting image and only update timer value. Any help is appreciated.

```
package com.shivam;

import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

public class QuizFrame extends Frame implements ActionListener {
    String[][] questions;
    String[][] answers;
    String[][] useranswers = new String[10][1];
    Label qno, question;
    Checkbox opt1, opt2, opt3, opt4;
    CheckboxGroup groupoptions;
    Button next, submit;
  //QuizRepository quizRepository;
    Image image;
    public static int timer = 15;
    public static int ans_given = 0;
    public static int count = 0;
    public static int score = 0;
    String name;
    QuizFrame(String name,QuizRepository quizRepository) {
        count = 0;
        this.name = name;
        setTitle("QuizApp - Quiz");
        setBackground(new Color(42, 20, 66));
        setForeground(Color.WHITE);
        setLayout(null);
//      quizRepository = new QuizRepository();
//      quizRepository.loadQuizFromDb();
        questions = quizRepository.getQuestions();
        answers = quizRepository.getAnswers();

        qno = new Label();
        qno.setBounds(350, 280, 40, 30);
        qno.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 24));
        add(qno);

        question = new Label();
        question.setBounds(410, 280, 850, 30);
        question.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 24));
        add(question);

        groupoptions = new CheckboxGroup();
        opt1 = new Checkbox();
        opt1.setCheckboxGroup(groupoptions);
        opt1.setBounds(420, 320, 300, 30);
        opt1.setFont(new Font("Dialog", Font.PLAIN, 20));
        add(opt1);

        opt2 = new Checkbox();
        opt2.setCheckboxGroup(groupoptions);
        opt2.setBounds(420, 360, 300, 30);
        opt2.setFont(new Font("Dialog", Font.PLAIN, 20));
        add(opt2);

        opt3 = new Checkbox();
        opt3.setBounds(420, 400, 300, 30);
        opt3.setCheckboxGroup(groupoptions);
        opt3.setFont(new Font("Dialog", Font.PLAIN, 20));
        add(opt3);

        opt4 = new Checkbox();
        opt4.setBounds(420, 440, 300, 30);
        opt4.setCheckboxGroup(groupoptions);
        opt4.setFont(new Font("Dialog", Font.PLAIN, 20));
        add(opt4);

        next = new Button("Next");
        next.setBounds(550, 500, 150, 40);
        next.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 22));
        next.setBackground(new Color(30, 144, 255));
        next.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
        next.addActionListener(this);
        add(next);

        submit = new Button("Submit");
        submit.setBounds(800, 500, 150, 40);
        submit.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 22));
        submit.setBackground(new Color(129, 131, 129));
        submit.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
        submit.addActionListener(this);
        submit.setEnabled(false);
        add(submit);

        start(count);
        setExtendedState(Frame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
        image = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage("src/resources/boy.png");
        //System.out.println(image.getGraphics());
        MediaTracker tracker = new MediaTracker(this);
        tracker.addImage(image,0);
        try {
            tracker.waitForID(0);
        }
        catch(InterruptedException ae){
            System.out.println("Exception occurred while loading image...");
        }
        setVisible(true);
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
        if (ae.getSource() == next) {
            repaint();
            opt1.setEnabled(true);
            opt2.setEnabled(true);
            opt3.setEnabled(true);
            opt4.setEnabled(true);

            ans_given = 1;
            if (groupoptions.getSelectedCheckbox() == null) {
                useranswers[count][0] = "";
            } else {
                useranswers[count][0] = groupoptions.getSelectedCheckbox().getLabel();
            }

            if (count == 8) {
                next.setEnabled(false);
                next.setBackground(new Color(129, 131, 129));
                submit.setEnabled(true);
                submit.setBackground(new Color(104, 239, 66));
            }
            count++;
            start(count);
        }
         else if (ae.getSource() == submit) {
            ans_given = 1;
            if (groupoptions.getSelectedCheckbox() == null) {
                useranswers[count][0] = "";
            } else {
                useranswers[count][0] = groupoptions.getSelectedCheckbox().getLabel();
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < useranswers.length; i++) {
                if (useranswers[i][0].equals(answers[i][1])) {
                    score += 10;
                }
            }
            setVisible(false);
            new ResultFrame(name,score);
            System.out.println("Score : "+score);
        }
    }

    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        super.paint(g);
        String time = "Time left - " + timer + " seconds"; // 15
        g.setColor(Color.RED);
        g.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 25));
        g.drawImage(image,950,300,null);
        if (timer > 0) {
            g.drawString(time, 600, 200);
        } else {
            g.drawString("Times up!!", 600, 200);
        }
        timer--; // 14
        try {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
            repaint();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        if (ans_given == 1) {
            ans_given = 0;
            timer = 15;
        } else if (timer < 0) {
            timer = 15;
            opt1.setEnabled(true);
            opt2.setEnabled(true);
            opt3.setEnabled(true);
            opt4.setEnabled(true);

            if (count == 8) {
                next.setEnabled(false);
                submit.setEnabled(true);
            }
            if (count == 9) { // submit button
                if (groupoptions.getSelectedCheckbox() == null) {
                    useranswers[count][0] = "";
                } else {
                    useranswers[count][0] = groupoptions.getSelectedCheckbox().getLabel();
                }
                for (int i = 0; i < useranswers.length; i++) {
                    if (useranswers[i][0].equals(answers[i][1])) {
                        score += 10;
                    }
                }
                setVisible(false);
                new ResultFrame(name,score);
                System.out.println("Score : "+score);
            } else { // next button
                if (groupoptions.getSelectedCheckbox() == null) {
                    useranswers[count][0] = "";
                } else {
                    useranswers[count][0] = groupoptions.getSelectedCheckbox().getLabel();
                }
                count++; // 0 // 1
                start(count);
            }
        }
    }
    public void start(int count) {
        if(count<=9) {
            qno.setText((count + 1) + ". ");
            question.setText(questions[count][0]);
            opt1.setLabel(questions[count][1]);
            opt2.setLabel(questions[count][2]);
            opt3.setLabel(questions[count][3]);
            opt4.setLabel(questions[count][4]);
            groupoptions.setSelectedCheckbox(null);
        }
    }

}
```

[image]

The boy image i have drawn in paint method and it repaints every second. I want to stop that.

Comment: 1) Why are you using AWT? You should at least be learning Swing if not newer alternatives. 2) A painting method is for painting only. That is you paint the current state of the class. The rest of you application has logic to change the state. So you should NOT be 1) using Thread.sleep(...). Use a Swing Timer for animation. 2) invoking repaint(). The Timer will invoke repaint() when it is fired. 3) Have game logic to check for end of game etc. You need to rewrite/restrucuture to the cod to remove all logic from the paint method.

Comment: 4) Don't use a null layout. Start by reading the [Swing tutotrial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/TOC.html)

Comment: I have to do it without swing and only awt

Comment: Whether you use AWT components or Swing components it doesn't change my suggestions.

Comment: I mean I cant use swing timer so i hit a dead end.

Comment: I've never used AWT (since its 20 years out of date) but you should be able to use a java.util.Timer.  Not sure if you need to wrap the code in the Timer in an EventQueue.invokeLater(...).

Comment: Alright i will look it up. Thanks